# Return vector<string> by reference

Tags: python, c++, swig

I have a SWIG class that receives an vector of strings -`vector<string>` (CSCHSwig), this class uses a. LIB another project that returns another vector of strings by reference.

CSCHSwig.cpp

```
#include CSCHSwig.h
vector < string> CSCHSwig::CSwig(vector < string> a_InputArgs){

    vector < string> a_OutputArgs;
    int resposta = ClassLib->SendRequest(a_InputArgs, a_OutputArgs);

    return a_OutputArgs
}
```

CSCHSwig.h

```
#include < string>
#include < vector> 
using namespace std;

class CSCHSwig { public:
    CSCHSwig();
    virtual ~CSCHSwig();
    vector <string> CSwig(const vector < string> a_InputArgs);
}
```

CSCHSwig.i

```
/* File : CSCHSwig.i */

%module CSCHSwig

%{
#include "..\..\..\Incl\CSCHSwig.h"
%}

%include <std_string.i>
%include <std_vector.i>
%include "typemaps.i"


namespace std {
    %template(a_OutpuArgs) vector < string>; 
}


%include "..\..\..\Incl\CSCHSwig.h"
```

An example of ClassLib:
ClassLib.cpp

```
int ClassLib::SendRequest(const vector < string>& a_InputArgs, vector < string>& a_OutputArgs, {
    vector < string> Vector;

    Vector.push_back("pReturnStatus");
    Vector.push_back("1");

    a_OutputArgs = Vector;

    return 1;
}
```

ClassLib.h

```
class ClassLib
{
public:
    int SendRequest(const vector < string>&  a_InputArgs, vector < string>& a_OutputArgs);
}
```

I've tested the SWIG class and it is working perfectly, I call CSwig method from python passing a list of strings. The problem is when the CSwig method calls the method SendRequest ClassLib. 
`int resposta = ClassLib->SendRequest(a_InputArgs, a_OutputArgs);`

Execution is terminated, returns no error. The tests I made the "mistake" happens when the a_OutputArgs argument is handled within the method and returns an array of strings. Maybe I need to put something in the .i file for this to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. I use MS Visual Studio 2008 and the setting was different projects. In Project Properties> General> Use of MFC set:

Use MFC in a Shared DLL